# Adding / Deleting rows without the usual copy paste method

Tags: excel, vba

I have 60 blocks of calculations in my excel model. Based on certain criteria, the model will generate 2 numbers. One determines the number of rows to be added and the other determines the number of rows to be deleted.

Based on these two numbers I have to EITHER add OR delete rows to each of the 60 blocks of calculation. So for each block, either the rows will be added or deleted but not both. I have created range names against each block in the form of "Check" & 'a' where 'a' goes from 1 to 60. These ranges contain either the addition or the deletion number. Have also created another set of 60 range names by the name "PStart" & 'a' to get the start cell of each block of calculation.

I have prepared a code using the usual method of copying the data and inserting the required number of rows but it is taking over 5 mins to add even 5 rows to each block.

Is there any other way to do this to speed up the process? Thanks for the help!

```
        Dim Rows, a As Long
        Dim rng, prng, sheetnm_rng As String

        For a = 1 To 60
        rng = "Check" & a
        prng = "PStart" & a
        sheetnm_rng = Range(rng).Parent.Name
        Rows = Range(rng).Value

        If Rows > 0 Then
            Sheets(sheetnm_rng).Range(prng).End(xlDown).EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets(sheetnm_rng).Range(prng).End(xlDown).EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rows).Insert shift:=xlDown
        ElseIf Rows < 0 Then
            Sheets(sheetnm_rng).Range(prng).End(xlDown).Offset(Rows + 1).Resize(-Rows).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        Next a
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using them. The description of [tag:excel-vba] that you used starts with the phrases **THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL.** , which means you should not use it for new questions. I've removed it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, which you might find useful:

https://www.quora.com/What-steps-can-I-take-to-speed-up-for-loops-in-Excel-VBA

points 3 and 4 seem important for your case.

3.- If you are using an older version of Excel, turn off Screen updating at the beginning of your code, and don’t bother turning it back on. Excel will do that for you automatically when the code finishes execution.

4.- If you are copying and pasting values but don’t need to paste the formats—don’t. It is faster to set the .Value property of one range to the .Value property of another range.

Also you can try to measure your Sub running time with the different options you try, to try to keep the best, even if it is not as fast as you would like. Find a code example:

```
Sub CalculateRunTime_Seconds()
'PURPOSE: Determine how many seconds it took for code to completely run
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

'Remember time when macro starts
  StartTime = Timer

'*****************************
'Insert Your Code Here...
'*****************************

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'Notify user in seconds
  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RustyBucketBay. Both points 3 and 4 are valid but unfortunately not applicable to my case. I am using Excel 365 and I do need to paste formulas. Also, I have been measuring the sub run time by this exact method but did not share that part of the code within my question. Thanks again!